# N-palindrome question, need to determine the second terminating case

Tags: java, recursion, palindrome

This recursive method finds the palindrome of a string based on the value of n. Where n is how many characters at each time are being compared
If n is 2, then "abab" is a palindrome because of ab and ab.

```
public static boolean nDrome(String s, int n)
{
      if(s.isEmpty())
         return true;
      else if( s.length() == 3 )
         return true;
      else
      {  
         if(s.substring(0,n).equals( s.substring(s.length()-n) ) )
            return nDrome( s.substring(n, s.length()-n), n);
         else
         return false;
      }
   }
```

The problem resides in my second if statement. 
Lets consider for example:

`nDrome("abcdefgcdab", 2);`

This is a palindrome because
AB, CD, EFG, CD, AB

Notice how the middle term doesn't count, so in this case the code works because there is a hardcoded value of 3 in the if. Now, if i were to change the n value, it would no longer work properly. How can i determine the second if statement's value?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch but in the case of n=1, wouldnt you just get whatever the length is? It would return true from the start

Comment: *"Notice how the middle term doesn't count"* How do you define "middle term" so it doesn't count? What makes it "not count"? Asked another way, what is the definition of an `N-palindrome`? I can't seem to find a definition that matches what you're doing.

Comment: @Andreas The middle term simply doesn't count because there is no other value to compare it to, the middle term in this case consists of 3 characters. the n is 2. 3-n would give you 1, which is not enough to compare to. The comparison must be of a pair of n characters to another pair of n characters. Hope that helps!

Comment: @Andreas Another example would be the classic "racecar". 
nDrome("racecar", 1). the terms being compared would be 
r and r, a and a, c and c, but now you're left with "e", that is the middle term in this case.

Comment: So if the middle term has length < 2 * n, then it can be ignored? In your example, a 3-length middle term can be ignored, but so could a 2-length or 1-length middle term? If not, why not?

Comment: @Andreas Wow, you are a genius! I just tried that in the IDE and seems to work on the cases i have tried so far, thank you :) I will test it out further and get back to you.